# How can I append a string into the first occurrence of a pattern?

Tags: bash, sed

Add a apple string when i find the first pattern of foo.

Input data:

```
foofoo
foobaz
foobez
```

Results:

```
apple
foofoo
foobaz
foobez
```

is that possible to do it using bash/sed ?
thanks

Comment: You mean prepend "apple" before the first line that starts with "foo"?

Comment: yes sound easy but seems hard to do it

Comment: this also kinda sounds like _homework_. Is it ?

Comment: No i just think it would be easy using 1 line bash code, but somehow it turns out that it is not in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'sed':

$ cat infile

```
foofoo
foobaz
foobez
```

$ cat script.sed

```
## The pattern 'foo' found in the line.
/foo/ {
        ## Check hold space, case of being blank, it's the first pattern 'foo' so
        ## I will print the word 'apple' before it.
        x
        /^$/ {
                i\
apple
                g
        }
        ## Go back to pattern space to print at the end of this script.
        x
}
```

$ sed -f script.sed infile

```
apple
foofoo
foobaz
foobez
```

Edit: Add a solution using a one-line sed command.

I don't know how to use the 'i\' command in one line, but next one is similar and it works.

```
$ sed '/foo/ { x ; /^$/ { g ; s/^/apple\n/ ; x }; x }' infile
apple
foofoo
foobaz
foobez
```

Answer (score 2):

Not bash/sed but perl, which is a speciality of mine.

`perl -pE 'say "apple" if /^foo/ and not $seen_foo++'`

For each line, say "apple" if the line starts with "foo" and we have not seen one such line before, then print the line.

Comment: Automatically `chomp`s each line and outputs line separator after each `print`. Allows me to skip printing `"\n"` manually, for cleaner code.

Comment: Good to know. I was under the impression that `-lpe` would need to fail because `pe` aren't valid octals. Sorry for my confusion

Comment: Anyway `-n` and `-p` together would conflict.

Comment: possible to do it under bash?

Comment: @Christoffer: well, apparently it doesn't and it is quite ubiquitously documented for use with oneliners. Upon rereading the manpage, I _will_ agree that the -n is redundant in that case.

Comment: @sehe: Yeah, i meant "conflict", as in "confusing and redundant".

Comment: @Kit Ho: You can call perl from bash if that's what you mean. Also, you could do this in pure bash, but that's too annoying to code when it can be made much cleaner in perl, which it's pretty likely that you have installed anyway.

Comment: @Kit Ho: To clarify, just pipe your input into this one liner.

Comment: @Christoffer: Can you specific how to make it works on a specific <file name>?

Comment: @Kit Ho: `perl -pE 'say "apple" if /^foo/ and not $seen_foo++' $FILENAME`

Comment: @Christoffer: would you mind explaining more on the code before I tick your answer?

Comment: @Kit Ho: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -i seen_foo=0;
while read line; do
  case "${line}" in
    *foo*)
    let seen_foo++
    [ $seen_foo -eq 1 ] && echo apple
    ;;
  esac
  echo "${line}"
done
```

Translated the perl answer to bash
If you save the above as /tmp/x and your input as /tmp/x1 you would run it like this

> bash /tmp/x < /tmp/x1

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that list is a file(?). So using just *`Bash`*(just for fun, perl is so much more powerful in its expressiveness) I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

newstr="$1"
filein="$2"
counter=0

while read -r; do
    ((counter++))
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^foo ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$newstr" "$REPLY"
        break # no need to loop anymore
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"
done < "$filein"

# just print the rest of the file
sed -n "$counter,$(wc -l < "$filein")p" "$filein"
```

use it like this:

```
$ that_script apples file
```

Inspired by my answer in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576416/bash-insert-line-into-source-code-file-after-initial-comments/6576527#6576527)

---

*NOTE*: this just looks if the string *starts with* `foo`. Place your own pattern, by changing the line below, to whatever suits you:

```
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^foo ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
nl=$'\n'
str='foofoo
foobaz
foobez
'
echo "${str/foo/apple${nl}foo}"
```